# How to get highest salary city wise

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, mapreduce, hiveql

I was asked this question in an interview (hopefully you guys can help me; thanks in advance).

In Hive, how would you get the highest salary city wise from employee table?

```
003 Amit Delhi India 12000
004 Anil Delhi India 15000
005 Deepak Delhi India 34000
006 Fahed Agra India 45000
007 Ravi Patna India 98777
008 Avinash Punjab India 120000
009 Saajan Punjab India 54000
001 Harit Delhi India 20000
002 Hardy Agra India 20000
```

Comment: I don't know hive, but in sql server I'd use `row_number` and select the record where `row_number` = n. I'd think something similar is possible in `hive`

Comment: can you give me query for this

Comment: Is salary really a department column, not an employee column?  That would mean your salary would be determined by which department you are in.

Comment: Do you mean the employee(s) with the nth highest salary?

Comment: The idea that salaries are arranged by department is a strange one. But very egalitarian I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SET @rank:=0;
 SET @dept:='';
 SET @desiredrank=8;  --For example. 

 SELECT ename, rank, salary
 FROM
 (
      SELECT
         ename, salary, 
         @rank:=CASE WHEN @dept=deptid THEN @rank+1 ELSE 1 END AS rank,
         @dept:=deptid AS department
      FROM employees e
      JOIN departments d
      ON e.deptid=d.deptid
      ORDER BY d.deptid, salary
 )
 WHERE rank=@desiredrank
```

Basically you have to use two extra variables.  One to simulate the grouping, and one to keep track of the rank.  When that query is done, filter it for the rank you want.

Answer (score -1):

```
Select Id , max(salary) from employee group by city;
```

In that case, every city with highest salary with respective id will be displayed.